# Anonymous BDC Authentication problem

Tags: business-data-catalog

We are using SP 2007 Enterprise and it's Business Data Catalogue to return data in web parts on our external web site to anonymous users (or am trying to in any case).

I haven't found any concrete examples of a working Application Definition File (LOB section), the settings required in the SSP and IIS to make this work.  Has anyone successfully set an external site to use the BDC?

My thoughts are to use an AD account to replace IUSR as the Anonymous account in IIS and enable it, add that user to the BDC permissions with Execute, and possibly add a property into each ADF method to allow anonymous calls;

Property Name="AllowAnonymousExecute" Type="System.Boolean" set to 'true'.

If anyone has written a blog or can identify the steps required, it would be extremely helpful.

Comment: I think you ought to be looking at SSO

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you're using passthrough authentication or SSO and the BDC source doesn't allow anonymous. Can you try using your web app's identity instead?